# Make namedtuple accept kwargs

Tags: python, python-2.7, keyword-argument, namedtuple

If I have a class like:

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, name, **kwargs):
        self.name = name

p = Person(name='joe', age=25) # age is ignored
```

Extra params are ignored. But if I have a `namedtuple`, I'll get `unexpected keyword argument:

```
from collections import namedtuple 

Person = namedtuple('Person', 'name')
p = Person(name='joe', age=25)

# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "python", line 1, in <module>
# TypeError: __new__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'age'
```

How can I make `namedtuple` accept `kwargs` so I can pass extra arguments safely?

Comment: The clues in the name.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following session in the interpreter shows one possible solution to fixing your problem:

```
Python 3.5.0 (v3.5.0:374f501f4567, Sep 13 2015, 02:27:37) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import collections
>>> class Person(collections.namedtuple('base', 'name')):
    __slots__ = ()
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        for key in tuple(kwargs):
            if key not in cls._fields:
                del kwargs[key]
        return super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)


>>> p = Person(name='joe', age=25)
>>> p
Person(name='joe')
>>>
```

---

**Alternative:**

Since you rather have a simpler solution, you might find the next program more to your liking:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import collections


def main():
    Person = namedtuple('Person', 'name')
    p = Person(name='joe', age=25)
    print(p)


def namedtuple(typename, field_names, verbose=False, rename=False):
    base = collections.namedtuple('Base', field_names, verbose, rename)
    return type(typename, (base,), {
        '__slots__': (),
        '__new__': lambda cls, *args, **kwargs: base.__new__(cls, *args, **{
            key: value for key, value in kwargs.items()
            if key in base._fields})})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Well, if I want to write a `__new__` method for every class I need, then I will just make a class like my first example. But thanks for your answer.

Comment: @norbertpy I've added a new implementation of `namedtuple` to take care of that problem automatically for you. It does the same thing as the first example but handles the change to `__new__` so you can avoid writing the code yourself.

Comment: Do not make subclasses of namedtuple without `__slots__`. It wastes memory.

Answer (score 14):

It's not pretty:

```
p = Person(*(dict(name='joe', age=25)[k] for k in Person._fields))
```

Answer (score 4):

A slight variation of @paulmcg answer using a factory method:

```
_Person = namedtuple('Person', 'name')

class Person(_Person):
    @staticmethod
    def from_dict(args):
        args = {k: v for k, v in args.items() if k in _Person._fields}
        return Person(**args)


p = Person.from_dict(dict(name='joe', age=25))
print(p)
```

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to wrap the `Person` class constructor to ignore arguments which aren't defined as fields of the `Person` namedtuple:

```
from collections import namedtuple
Person = namedtuple('Person', 'name')

def make_person(*args, **kwargs):
    person_args = {}

    # process positional args
    if len(args) > len(Person._fields):
        msg = "Person() takes %d positional arguments but %d were given" % (len(Person._fields), len(args))
        raise TypeError(msg)
    for arg_name, arg_value in zip(Person._fields, args):
        person_args[arg_name] = arg_value

    # process keyword args
    for arg_name, arg_value in kwargs.items():
        try:
            i = Person._fields.index(arg_name)
        except ValueError:
            pass # ignore arguments not defined as Person fields
        else:
            if arg_name in person_args:
                msg = "make_person() got multiple values for argument " + repr(arg_name)
                raise TypeError(msg)
            person_args[arg_name] = arg_value

    if len(person_args) != len(Person._fields):
        msg = "Person() requires additional arguments: "
        msg += ", ".join([repr(x) for x in Person._fields if x not in person_args])
        raise TypeError(msg)
    return Person(*[person_args[x] for x in Person._fields])
```

Given the above:

```
>>> make_person('a')
Person(name='a')
>>> make_person('a', b='b')
Person(name='a')
>>> make_person('a', name='b')
TypeError: make_person() got multiple values for argument 'name'
>>> make_person(b='b')
TypeError: Person() requires additional arguments: 'name'
>>> make_person(1, 2)
TypeError: Person() takes 1 positional arguments but 2 were given
```

Comment: Unlike Paul's answer, this answer supports combining positional and keyword arguments correctly, and properly deals with all of the edge cases with informative error messages.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to have this useful little library, I recently handled a similar situation like so:

```
import funcy
data = {"lots": "of", "keys": "here"}
trip = Trip(**funcy.project(data, Trip._fields))
```

`funcy` Library: https://github.com/Suor/funcy#readme

`project` function: https://funcy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/colls.html#project

[image: Return a dict containing only those entires in mapping whose key is in keys]

Answer (score -1):

Straightforward, just give your `namedtuple` a `kwargs` field and set its default value to an empty dictionary. Then any key-value pair can be added and accessed under that `kwargs` field, see the sample code below.

```
from collections import namedtuple 

Person = namedtuple('Person', 'name, kwargs', defaults=['', {}])
p = Person(name='joe', kwargs={'age': 25})

print(p)
print(p.kwargs['age'])

p2 = Person()

print(p2)
```

**Output:**

> Person(name='joe', kwargs={'age': 25})
>
> 25
>
> Person(name='', kwargs={})

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?